# Gitlab trigger pipeline when on main and tag

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, rules

We want to trigger a pipeline when devs push some code on main branch and tag the version. To do this we wrote a pipeline defined in this way:

```
image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

stages:
    - build_upload

build, package and upload:
    stage: build_upload
    script:
        - mvn package
    rules:
        - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main' && $CI_COMMIT_TAG != null
```

But the pipeline is never trigged. Any idea on why? We printed the two variables and the pipe reports:
main
v0.0.1

Thanks in advance